# Separate cache or new DB? Load of application too slow

Tags: laravel, caching, ember.js

I am working on a GPS system which uses EmberJS and Laravel frameworks.

We currently read all the IMEI's and their relative data from a PgSQL DB. This is very time consuming and causes the load time of the application to be too slow for an application which one of it's main POI is real-time data.

Does this sound possible/feasible way of speeding this process up.. load all of the data into the cache using the IMEI of the device as its unique identifier.

The cache will run a check to see if any field has changed for a certain IMEI in the DB on a selected schedule. If it has then updated, then the data regarding the IMEI will be read and updated from the DB instantly.

The application will then make a GET request to retrieve any new data which has been modified.

So this would now read directly from cache upon application load, not from the database. Although any updated information would come directly from there.

For example, devices which are immobilised are a drain on our CPU. They're constantly getting pulled from the database despite their obvious off state, in a cache they'd only be pulled from the cache again once their immobilisation state changes.

If this idea is bad then why? and what alternative do you suggest?

Comment: Any suggestions regarding this?